# G++ undefined re ference to `WinMain' (No IDE)

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++

So I am coding a class outside of my main.cpp caled Do_Encode it is referenced in DoEncoding.h:

```
#ifndef DOENCODING_H
#define DOENCODING_H

class Do_Encode
{
    public:
        void print();
};

#endif
```

and the class itself is on DoEncoding.cpp:

```
#include "..\Header\DoEncoding.h"

void Do_Encode::print()
{

}
```

I code with notepad++ so i have to compile it all by hand.

When I compile DoEncoding.cpp into DoEncoding.o, to later link to Main.o I get the error

"(A very long path): undefined re ference to `WinMain'

collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status"

I foud that many people get this error by not creating a console aplication in their IDE but I don't have an IDE so how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this with a bit of Googling: https://justcheckingonall.wordpress.com/2008/08/29/console-window-win32-app/

But if you don't actually need the console window for anything, I think it's enough to solve your problem to just include an empty WinMain function in your main.cpp, like this:

```
int WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                 HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                 LPSTR     lpCmdLine,
                 int       nCmdShow)
{return 0;}
```